# Calling javascript function with two different tags with same id

Tags: javascript, html

I am using two select tag which are completely identical, their id also.

```
<select name ="state" id ="state" onclick="populateStates2('state')"></select>
<select name ="state" id ="state" onclick="populateStates2('state')"></select>
```

and my js:

```
populateStates('state');

var state_arr = new Array("Andaman and Nicobar Islands","Andhra Pradesh","Arunachal Pradesh","Assam","Bihar","Chandigarh","Chhattisgarh","Dadra and Nagar Haveli","Daman and Diu","Delhi","Goa","Gujarat","Haryana","Himachal Pradesh","Jammu and Kashmir","Jharkhand","Karnataka","Kerala","Lakshadweep","Madhya Pradesh","Maharashtra","Manipur","Meghalaya","Mizoram","Nagaland","Orissa","Pondicherry","Punjab","Rajasthan","Sikkim","Tamil Nadu","Tripura","Uttar Pradesh","Uttaranchal","West Bengal");

function populateStates2(stateElementId){
// given the id of the <select> tag as function argument, it inserts <option> tags
var stateElement = document.getElementById(stateElementId);
stateElement.length=0;
stateElement.options[0] = new Option('Select state','-1');
stateElement.selectedIndex = 0;
for (var i=0; i<state_arr.length; i++) {
    stateElement.options[stateElement.length] = new Option(state_arr[i],state_arr[i]);
}
```

}

So here, I am calling populateStates two times by different tags with same id, but only first select tag works. Is there any workaround so that I can call both of them but with same id/name/classname ? 
I want to run the function one time .

Comment: Two different tags should not have the same ID, use classes instead

Comment: Id is meant to be unique.

Comment: @boehm_s I am editing my post, please see the function body of populateStates as well, and answer

Comment: id's have to be used as unique identifier's. work with classes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make the DOM behave properly while having to strictly identical IDs. IDs are meant to be very specific and unique Inside the DOM.
Basically are used to create an index of HTML elements that can be accessed faster than the regular tag or class selector.

You should however use a class, or handle the selection directly by tag name or with the querySelection javascript method.

https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/att_global_id.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute a function when clicking on an element, you should pass `this` to your function :

```
<tag onclick="populateStates2(this)"></tag>
```

Then, you will have your element as the first parameter of your function :

```
function populateStates2(myElement) {
  // do stuff with myElement
}
```

So, you have a function that takes an element as first parameter and do stuff with it.
If you want to applie this function to multiples elements, you can call it as many times as you want with your desired elements.

To group elements together, you can use classes :

```
<tag id="id1" class="led_zep"> </tag>
<tag id="id2" class="led_zep"> </tag>
```

Then, you can loop over it and call your function :

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('led_zep')).forEach(function(myElem) {
  populateStates2(myElem);
});
```

**EDIT**

If you want the `onclick` function to be set programmatically, just do like that :

```
var myClickableElem = document.getElementById('id1');
myClickableElem.onclick = function() {
  populateStates2(myElem);
}
```

To do the same for multiples elements :

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('led_zep')).forEach(function(myElem) {
  myElem.onclick = function() {
    populateStates2(myElem);
  }
});
```

Hope it helps,
Best regards,

Comment: Is there a way that I can avoid using onclick event in tag itself ?

Comment: Yes, that's why I put the `Array.from` method, that allows me to turn `NodeList` or `HTMLCollections` into Arrays

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `getElementById`, you can use either `getElementsByTagName()[index]` or `getElementsByName()[index]`

Both of them return HTML Collection.

So, rewrite this code as below

```
<select name ="state" id ="state" onclick="populateStates2('state',0)"></select>
<select name ="state" id ="state" onclick="populateStates2('state',1)"></select>
```

Then your function as

```
var state_arr = ["Andaman and Nicobar Islands","Andhra Pradesh","Arunachal Pradesh","Assam","Bihar","Chandigarh","Chhattisgarh","Dadra and Nagar Haveli","Daman and Diu","Delhi","Goa","Gujarat","Haryana","Himachal Pradesh","Jammu and Kashmir","Jharkhand","Karnataka","Kerala","Lakshadweep","Madhya Pradesh","Maharashtra","Manipur","Meghalaya","Mizoram","Nagaland","Orissa","Pondicherry","Punjab","Rajasthan","Sikkim","Tamil Nadu","Tripura","Uttar Pradesh","Uttaranchal","West Bengal"];

function populateStates2(stateElementId,index){
    var stateElement = document.getElementsByName(stateElementId)[index];
    stateElement.length=0;
    stateElement.options[0] = new Option('Select state','-1');
    stateElement.selectedIndex = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<state_arr.length; i++){
        stateElement.options[stateElement.length] = new Option(state_arr[i],state_arr[i]);
    }
}
```

### Note

Here we didn't used the `id` attribute.

In a page, `id` should be unique.